# Recipe seems to ignore condition inside loop

Tags: shell, loops, if-statement, gnu-make

I have this recipe on my make file:

```
.PHONY: matlab                                         
matlab: $(matlab_files)                                
  set -x;for f in `echo "$^"`; do\                     
    base=`basename $$f`;\                              
    if [[ ! -f "$(matlab_dir_name)/$${base}" ]]; then\ 
      ln -s $$f $(matlab_dir_name)/$${base}; \         
    fi;\                                               
  done;set +x
```

that is, I want to check if link exists before making it. But the if test seems to be ignored. With the debug option showed above, I get the following lines:

```
+ for f in '`echo "MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/d3pd_export.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/matd3pd.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/net2py.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/cluster_size.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/create_cluster.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getEffAtThres.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getThresAndEff.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m"`'
++ basename MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m
+ base=scanparam.m
+ [[ ! -f matlab/scanparam.m ]]
+ ln -s MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m matlab/scanparam.m
ln: matlab/scanparam.m: File exists
+ for f in '`echo "MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/d3pd_export.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/matd3pd.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/net2py.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/cluster_size.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/create_cluster.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getEffAtThres.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getThresAndEff.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m"`'
++ basename MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m
+ base=script_normal_train_offline.m
+ [[ ! -f matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m ]]
+ ln -s MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m
ln: matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m: File exists
+ for f in '`echo "MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/d3pd_export.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/matd3pd.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/net2py.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/cluster_size.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/create_cluster.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getEffAtThres.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getThresAndEff.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m"`'
++ basename MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m
+ base=trainBinaryClassifier.m
+ [[ ! -f matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m ]]
+ ln -s MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m
ln: matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m: File exists
+ for f in '`echo "MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/d3pd_export.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/matd3pd.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/net2py.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/cluster_size.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/create_cluster.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getEffAtThres.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getThresAndEff.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m"`'
++ basename MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m
+ base=trainRinger.m
+ [[ ! -f matlab/trainRinger.m ]]
+ ln -s MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m matlab/trainRinger.m
ln: matlab/trainRinger.m: File exists
+ for f in '`echo "MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/d3pd_export.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/matd3pd.m MatlabD3PDImport/matlab/net2py.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/cluster_size.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/create_cluster.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getEffAtThres.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/getThresAndEff.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/scanparam.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/script_normal_train_offline.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainBinaryClassifier.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/trainRinger.m MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m"`'
++ basename MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m
+ base=xValidateBinaryClassifier.m
+ [[ ! -f matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m ]]
+ ln -s MatlabRingerTrain/matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m
ln: matlab/xValidateBinaryClassifier.m: File exists
+ set +x
```

Why is shell ignoring the if test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f FILE` checks if the file exists and is a regular file. To include symlinks in the test either use `-h`/`-L` (symlinks only) or `-e` (all files).

```
if [[ ! -e "$(matlab_dir_name)/$${base}" ]]; then
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just discovering that the error was with the symlink, as matlab was having trouble to run the symbolic link as well. I changed it to hard links, and both `-f` test and matlab recognizes the file. Fortunately, your answer just gives all information that was lacking to close the thread.